# What are the best algorithms to achieve probabilistic quantum cloning?

Tags: no-cloning-theorem, cloning

I am aware that there are algorithms that can clone states with unit fidelity but with a positive probability of failure. What would be the best known algorithms to create a perfect clone of an arbitrary unknown single qubit state with minimum probability of failure?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4528/55